# about cache in sql adapter of mobilefirst platform at android

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Where does the init creates the collections at android device?
I use android 4.4.4....

Comment: Your question is unclear. Provide a better description.

Comment: init? sql adapter? collections? Are you talking about JSONStore? Edit the question to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very much not clear. But I will assume you're actually referring to JSONStore. If you're not referring to JSONStore, well, make an effort to write a sensible question.

Review the following topic for the storage locations of JSONStore in devices: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_jsonstore_troubleshooting_overview.html

```
Android emulator:
$ adb shell
$ cd /data/data/com.<app-name>/databases/wljsonstore
$ sqlite3 jsonstore.sqlite  

iOS simulator:
$ cd ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/<id>/Documents/wljsonstore
$ sqlite3 jsonstore.sqlite

Windows Phone 8 (Silverlight):
$ cd C:\Data\Users\DefApps\AppData\<id>\Local\wljsonstore
$ sqlite3 jsonstore.sqlite

Windows 8 simulator
$ cd C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\<id>\LocalState\wljsonstore
$ sqlite3 jsonstore.sqlite

Note: JavaScript only implementation that runs on a web browser (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Internet Explorer) does not use an SQLite database. The file is stores in HTML5 LocalStorage.
```

Comment: Thanks dear for your decisive response, I have browsed through my Android device but its cache and file both are empty at USB storage>Android>data>com.app_name. Though I locally store data in my device and my android app refers this data stored in local storage collection.

Comment: Dear I want to know the location of JSONstore at android device's storage